# ¿Cómo abrir una aplicación de consola en Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio, cmd, exe, console

¿Alguien sabría cómo llamar desde Java a una aplicación de consola realizada en Visual Studio?
Consigo ejecutarla mediante:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\source\\repos\\Holamundo\\Holamundo\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Holamundo.exe")
```

Pero no consigo ver la ventana de consola con la ejecución.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones: mostrar el texto de salida de la ejecución leyéndolo desde el proceso:

```
OutputStream output = p.getOutputStream();
```

o ejecutar ese comando desde una consola:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "cmd.exe /c C:\\Users\\Usuario\\source\\repos\\Holamundo\\Holamundo\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\Holamundo.exe")
```

Comment: Gracias pero sigo sin poder ejecutar el Holamundo.exe.. que solo muestra un Holamundo mediante Console.WriteLine

Comment: @Jorge haz que tu exe se mantenga abierto durante más tiempo, por ejemplo ponle un timer. Suponiendo que se abra la consola (hace tiempo que no pruebo esto), una vez acabado el comando se cerrará automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76. Al final encontré esta solución que me vino bien. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Jorge Si consideras que esa solución es la correcta, puedes añadirla como respuesta. No hay ningún problema en responder a tus propias preguntas e incluso aceptarlas